# Как описать загрузку звуков с мобильного устройства в ImageButton

Tags: eclipse, android, java

Подскажите, как описать загрузку звуков с мобильного устройства в `ImageButton`? Нашёл только как с уже загруженными звуками в папке ресурсов оттуда вытаскивать. А нужно именно с sd-карты, например.

Comment: Вопрос из разряда "Какой компьютер лучше windows или pentium"    
В ImageButton нельзя загрузить звуки.

Comment: я загрузил их через ресурсы assets, проигрываются, всё нормально, через класс SoundPool! мне нужно именно, чтобы можно было с самого устройства загружать. это невозможно?

Comment: Там же в SoundPool есть метод load(String path, int priority)